# Creating multiple instances of dialog box

Tags: jquery, dialog, modal-dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm new to jQuery and java and I'm really trying to get my head round creating multiple instances of a dialog box. I'm using this in the head:

```
 <script src="external/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
 <script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

If I just have 1 button and and dialog box it works. But when I add another it stops working. I'm sure it will be quite easy to fix I'm just struggling.

```
        <h2>subjects</h2>

        <button id="opener">maths</button>

        <div id="dialog" title="Dialog Title">maths is an important subject.</div> <br> 

      <button id="opener">english</button>

        <div id="dialog" title="Dialog Title">this is also very important</div> <br>

       <script>

        $( "#dialog" ).dialog({ autoOpen: false });
        $( "#opener" ).click(function() {
        $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
                                         });
        </script>
```

Answer (score 5):

http://jsfiddle.net/y7952dmf/

1. ID must be unique and therefore used the class in order to work with several other elements of the same time
2. To link button and the dialog for example, use data-id for button and id for dialog with same value

**HTML:**

```
<h2>subjects</h2>

<button class="opener" data-id="#dialog1">maths</button>
<div class="dialog" id="dialog1" title="Dialog Title">maths is an important subject.</div>
<br>

<button class="opener" data-id="#dialog2">english</button>
<div class="dialog" id="dialog2" title="Dialog Title">this is also very important</div>
<br>
```

**JQ:**

```
//create all the dialogue
$(".dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false
});

//opens the appropriate dialog
$(".opener").click(function () {
    //takes the ID of appropriate dialogue
    var id = $(this).data('id');
   //open dialogue
    $(id).dialog("open");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

IDs are used to tell it what object you are working with. You need to give them separate names to have it know what to work with.

```
  <h2>subjects</h2>

    <button id="openerMath">maths</button>

    <div id="dialogMath" title="Dialog Title">maths is an important subject.</div> <br> 

  <button id="openerEnglish">english</button>

    <div id="dialogEnglish" title="Dialog Title">this is also very important</div> <br>

   <script>

    $( "#dialogMath" ).dialog({ autoOpen: false });
    $( "#openerMath" ).click(function() {
    $( "#dialogMath" ).dialog( "open" );
                                     });
    $( "#dialogEnglish" ).dialog({ autoOpen: false });
    $( "#openerEnglish" ).click(function() {
    $( "#dialogEnglish" ).dialog( "open" );
                                     });
    </script>
```

This should be what you are looking for.