# How can I make a dialog for each of multiple divs?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, flexbox

I am trying to make a small dashboard that I can check every morning to give me an easy way to tell if something failed the night before. The basic idea is for it to be flex divs with 2 in each row.

[image: Sample DBA dashboard]

I don't play with HTML or JavaScript a lot. I was trying to use pure JS to make a div appear like a popout but I was having issues with z-index and flex divs so I am trying to use some JQuery to make things easier for me.

The idea is that each of those blocks is hiding a 'details' div that has more information. Clicking on those boxes is supposed to display the test of that div as a dialog.

I can get one working just fine. My issue is trying to get all of the dialogs initialized so that I can click to open them at me leisure. After reading on how to [properly initialize dialogs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1701942/jquery-ui-dialog-opens-only-once) I tried to implement it.

My issue is that I get no response or feedback from this so I do not know what I am doing incorrectly.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Initialize all of the dialogs on this page
  $('.details').each(function() {
    $(this).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      width: 450,
      height: 550,
      buttons: {
        blah: function() {
          $(this).dialog("close");
        }
      }
    });
  });

  // Capture click event on all job class tables.
  $('.flex-item').click(function() {
    // look for a child element with the details class and opens its dialog
    $(this).find('.details').dialog('open');
  });
});
```

```css
#container {
  width: 1050px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-content: flex-start;
}

#container .flex-item {
  background: tomato;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 80px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  z-index: 500;
  cursor: default;
}

.flex-item .job {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  color: white;
}

.flex-item .dataGood,
.dataBad {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;
}

.flex-item .details {
  background-color: white;
  visibility: hidden;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 8px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10000;
  bottom: 125%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -80px;
}

.flex-item .dataGood {
  background-color: green;
}

.flex-item .dataBad {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div class="job">Title</div>
    <div class="dataGood">Date</div>
    <div class="details">This is the hidden stuff</div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div class="job">NIGHTLY WHOLE BACKUP on KANOR1</div>
    <div class="dataGood">03/08/2017 20:00:00</div>
    <div class="details">This is the hidden stuff</div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div class="job">DataMaint.Full Backup on KANSAGESQL</div>
    <div class="dataGood">03/08/2017 20:00:00</div>
    <div class="details">This is the hidden stuff</div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div class="job">Backup Failure Error 18204 on SQL08R2VM</div>
    <div class="dataBad">03/08/2017 20:00:00</div>
    <div class="details">This is the hidden stuff</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[For the fiddlers](https://jsfiddle.net/jk084d9q/1/)

Comment: even though I do have a functioning workaround if someone has an answer as to why the Jquery was not working I would welcome that information as well.

Comment: I'm guessing you need unique id's to fix that: [creating-multiple-instances-of-dialog-box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27238592/creating-multiple-instances-of-dialog-box) ... if that helps you I can add a note and a link in my answer

Comment: @LGSon That looks promising. I am busy implementing your current answer but I will be looking at that as well to see as well. I would add that into your answer anyway. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: You're welcome...and I added that link to my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using CSS hover and `transform`

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jk084d9q/6/)

```css
#container {
  width: 1050px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-content: flex-start;
  border: solid, 1px;
}
#container .flex-item {
  position: relative;
  background: tomato;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 80px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  cursor: default;
}
.flex-item .job {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  color: white;
}
.flex-item .dataGood,
.dataBad {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;
}

.flex-item .details {
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  transform: scaleY(0);
}
.flex-item .dataGood {
  background-color: green;
}
.flex-item .dataBad {
  background-color: red;
}
.flex-item:hover {
  z-index: 10;
}
.flex-item:hover .details {
  transform: scaleY(1);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div class="job">Title</div>
    <div class="dataGood">Date</div>
    <div class="details">This is the hidden stuff</div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div class="job">NIGHTLY WHOLE BACKUP on KANOR1</div>
    <div class="dataGood">03/08/2017 20:00:00</div>
    <div class="details">This is the hidden stuff</div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div class="job">DataMaint.Full Backup on KANSAGESQL</div>
    <div class="dataGood">03/08/2017 20:00:00</div>
    <div class="details">This is the hidden stuff</div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div class="job">Backup Failure Error 18204 on SQL08R2VM</div>
    <div class="dataBad">03/08/2017 20:00:00</div>
    <div class="details">This is the hidden stuff</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

As a side note, and me being more a CSS/plain javascript guy, I'm still guessing you need unique `id`'s to make your jQuery dialogs to work:

- [creating-multiple-instances-of-dialog-box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27238592/creating-multiple-instances-of-dialog-box)

Comment: What appears to be an incredibly simple workaround to me issue. Thanks.

Comment: So scaley of 0 is what is hiding it and scaley of 1 sets normal proportions for the div which allows us to see it. It also appears over the divs below. Wonderful.

Comment: @Matt That is correct, scale on `details` shows/hides, z-index on `flex-item` move them on top

Answer (score 0):

I think it will work for you :

```
$(this).find( ".details" ).dialog( "destroy" );
  // Capture click event on all job class tables.
  $('.flex-item').click(function() {
      $(this).find( ".details" ).dialog( "instance" );
      $(this).find( ".details" ).dialog({
          height: 400
       });
  });
```

Comment: Can you explain how this helps me? I am to understand that [`destroy`](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#method-destroy) restore the element to its orig state so my init function is useless now? Instance is supposed to return an object that you do not use so I don't see what that is doing here.  Answering my first question will likely explain what you are only setting the height in your snippet.

Comment: we need to setup dialog box. before open it that's why i given height also your init for dialogs is useless

Comment: I understand that but I currently try to set it up with `$('.details').each(function() { ...`. Am I not supposed to do that then? is your JS supposed to replace mine in my example?